# Star in the menu for the post in the chat

Tags: discussion, chat, design, chat-stars

My question is about design of the menu of the post in the chat.
Menu for the post from another user contains three items (flag, star, reply):

- for a post unstarred yet:

  > [image: no star]
- for a post starred by another user:

  > [image: one star]

In either cases star in the menu is a black, but another items are still gray.

Why star is drawn in black color despite the post is starred or not?

Comment: The arrow is the same color it appears afterwards too.